# Get original source of embed .NET function

Tags: c#, fonts, typeconverter

i am working to a project that will create a font dynamicly for C#
For that i use the function ConvertFromString of the Fontconverter class of the namespace System.ComponentModel.
its point is to create a font from a string
Ex:

```
var cvt = new FontConverter();
Label newLabel = new Label();
coolLabel.Font = cvt.ConvertFromString("Microsoft Sans Serif; 8,25; style=Bold") as Font;
```

But i would like to create dynamicly string with all options, its really hard to work with the original function and i would like to get the source of it.
 I tried googling for the function source & on the .net repos of dotnet but could not find the sosaid function.
I also tried looking trought VS Code 2019, no result
(Just showed me a Resume, parameters, returns, exceptions as a comments
So, if anyone can help me getting the original function so i can get my work done, thanks.
To be more clear, i want to "translate" this C# function to NodeJS so i can send NodeJS generated font so C# work on it.
Note: i DID checked on StackOverflow but did not found any question like mine that could help me.

Comment: Are you sure it's in `System.ComponentModel`?  The only `FontCoverter` I [can find](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/FontConverter.cs) is in `System.Drawing`.

Comment: My bad yeah, TypeConverter is from ComponentModel, sorry abouty this mystake, i am gonna change my post

Comment: Aftyer what you told me Kirk I checked and no in fact its in miltiple locations, take a look https://i.xpyth.dev/cx4nxLF2.png

Comment: `FontConverter` which is in `System.Drawing` subclasses `TypeConverter` which is in `System.ComponentModel`.  So yes, some of its behavior exists in two places.

Comment: Okay, so what am i supposed to do now ? :/

Comment: I don't understand.  Your question is literally asking for the source code, and as you can see you can view all the source code you want.  So what are you asking for now?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a .NET Decompiler to have a look under the hood.
I used dotPeek in the past which performed well

Comment: I did, i tried  with dnSpy but inside the class, could not find the function call :/